# Cannot connect Docker container to Weave network

Tags: networking, docker, weave

I am trying to connect two Docker containers on different hosts with a Weave overlay network. On my first host, I could connect to the Weave network without any problems. But on the other host my command line freezes whenever I'm trying to run a container with that network or when I'm trying to attach an existing container to that network later on.

Those are the commands I am using:

```
docker run -id --name test_container --net=weave test_img
```

and:

```
docker run -id --name test_container test_img
weave attach test_container
```

In both cases the command line is blocking and `ctrl+c` cannot stop the command. When I close the terminal and open a new one, I can see the container when I execute `docker ps -a`. But when I want to start it, the same things happens again.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out I didn't point the Weave router on the second host to the correct IP of the first host. When running `weave status` I saw that the connection failed. Running `weave connect <IP>` with the correct IP address solved the problem. Still strange, that running a Docker container blocks the command line instead of just returning an error message, though.